# SQL Server: how to get percentage that are true

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple SQL Server table of user loan applications.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Application] 
(
    [Id]          INT            NOT NULL,
    [ApplicantId] INT            NOT NULL,
    [LoanAmount]  INT            NOT NULL,
    [LoanTerm]    SMALLINT       NOT NULL,
    [Accepted]    BIT            NOT NULL,
    [BuyerId]     SMALLINT       NOT NULL,
    [Commission]  DECIMAL (9, 2) NOT NULL,
    [PostTime]    SMALLINT       NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn]   DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Application_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([ApplicantId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Applicant] ([Id])
);
```

I want to create a view over the table that provides two pieces of information. Firstly, the average time to process the application, and secondly, the percentage of applications that were accepted.

It's the second element I'm unsure about — I'm a complete SQL novice.

Here's what I have so far:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[PostPerformance]
AS 
    SELECT AVG(PostTime) AS 'AvgPostTime'
    FROM [Application]
```

As you can see `AvgPostTime` is simply enough but I'm unsure about how to calculate the percentage of loans that were accepted over a specific period.

Each row will have a 'true' or 'false' Accepted field — I'll need to count the number of entries that are true, and count the total rows in the selection, then calculate a percentage.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Could u provide us with some data into table, and the desired result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not provided sample data. I guess you are looking for this:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(PostTime) AS 'AvgPostTime'
    , 100.0 * count(case when [Accepted] = 1 then 1 end) / count(*) AS [Percentage]
FROM [Application]
```